# Why would Linux use swap space when there is so much buffer/cache available?

Tags: linux, memory, cache

When would Linux choose to swap out instead of using the free memory or buff/cache space?

Here is my data on my computer:

```
$ free
            total      used      free    shared  buff/cache  available
Mem:    528011992  51967272  43464000   1285108   432580720  472048004
Swap:    30769148       780  30768368
```

As we can see, I still have 43Gb of free RAM and 432Gb of buff/cache used. Why would Linux decide to use 780Kb of swap in that situation?

I thought I understood memory management in Linux, but I'm at a loss in this situation.

---

Maybe useful info: I am running several VPS and I'm pretty sure that their memory isn't committed by default (I'm pretty sure because I have one which I set with 32Gb of RAM and on a reboot I don't see that memory used up). Could the reserved 43Gb be in link with that?

Another note: my computer has two CPUs and the RAM uses NUMA, which is something new to me. Although I could imagine that having an impact, 43Gb of free RAM... and the kernel decides to swap...

Also, I read these answers [why is some of my swap space being used, when I still have unused RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/116003) but it did not really help much. I'm pretty sure I understand the basics.

---

Some of the commands I've found in link with my search here:

- `free`

As shown above, the `free` command shows me that some of the swap space is in use.

- `grep` of `/proc/*/status`

As shown in many answers, I checked each process status file. None of my processes is using swap space in this way (all show `0 Kb`).

- `ipcs` -- shared memory used to communicate between processes (IPC)

The swap is clearly not used by IPC:

```
$ ipcs -mu
------ Shared Memory Status --------
segments allocated 144
pages allocated 5775722
pages resident  1174430
pages swapped   0
Swap performance: 0 attempts     0 successes
```

- `mount` to check the `tmpfs`

Here is the output gathered, but I don't really see anything that would imply that one or more of these are currently using swap space:

```
$ mount | grep tmpfs
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=263958560k,nr_inodes=65989640,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=52801160k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/125 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=52801160k,mode=700,uid=125,gid=126)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=52801160k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1004)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=52801160k,mode=755)
```

Although I don't see anything here, I'm still thinking that it should be the `tmpfs` system that makes use of some swap space.

So my current question would be: How can I see how much swap space the `tmpfs` system is currently using?